# InstallShield setup and Click-Once

Tags: clickonce, installation, installshield

InstallShield 10 apparently can create an installer and integrate with click once, but this feature is not active in trial version. Anyway I tried to create a click once deployment by hand (using mage) and succeed with a sample wpf application, what I want to do is click once with an installShield setup.exe file, buy it seems that it's not a .net application and I can't use it for click once.
Does anyone know how installShield manages this with it's click once feature? or how can I create click once with the regular setup.exe file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to create a ClickOnce deployment and wrap it in installshield so the user only has a setup.exe to run?

Or are you trying to get ClickOnce to include and run an installer?

Or do you have something you want to install with InstallShield and you want ClickOnce to install it as a prerequisite?

Comment: what I'm trying to do is get click once to download and execute an installer

Comment: What does the installer do? You realize if it requires any kind of administrative privileges, ClickOnce won't be able to run it?